# Controlar tamaño de fotografía al subirla a la base de datos en blob

Tags: java, mysql, blob

Me gustaría poder controlar el tamaño de las fotos que suben desde mi programa de escritorio **JAVA/SE** a la base de datos **MySQL**. Poder limitar el tamaño de la imagen o el maximo de anchura/altura que se va a guardar en la base de datos.

Por ahora tengo un método que sube la foto pero no controlo el tamaño.

```
//Creo la conexión

static Connection connection = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection =DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://midominio.org:3306/nombreDB", "usuario", "contraseña");

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileFilter imageFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Imágenes", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
        chooser.setFileFilter(imageFilter);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        if(file != null)
        {
            BufferedImage img;
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                img=ImageIO.read(file);

                Image img2 = img.getScaledInstance(50, 67, 50);

                ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img2);

                fotoLb.setIcon(icon);

                fotoLb.revalidate();
                fotoLb.repaint();

                fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                String sentencia = "UPDATE persona SET FOTOGRAFIA = ? WHERE id_persona = ?";

                PreparedStatement pst;
                try {
                    pst = connection.prepareStatement(sentencia);
                    pst.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());
                    pst.setInt(2,idPersona);

                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    pst.close();

                } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {

                }
            }
```

En el método pst.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length()) El tercer parámetro indica que es el tamaño del archivo pero no se si dejándolo a un tamaño fijo el archivo se haría mas pequeño. ¿Habría alguna manera de controlar el tamaño de la imagen usando este metodo?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor que podrías hacer es redimencionar la imagen, en este caso cambiar el tamaño de alto y ancho (width, height), y así aunque se tome la foto con una cámara de mayores dimensiones tu internamente la vas a redimensionar, esto te ayuda bastante para disminuir tiempos de respuesta.

Podrías intentar algo como esto:

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage bufferedImage, int newW, int newH) {
        int w = bufferedImage.getWidth();
        int h = bufferedImage.getHeight();
        BufferedImage bufim = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, bufferedImage.getType());
        Graphics2D g = bufim.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g.dispose();
        return bufim;
    }
```

Comment: Los parametros newW y newH son pixeles? gracias

Comment: Si que me sirve, voy a compartir el código completo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
El código completo se me quedaría asi.

//Creo la conexión

static Connection connection = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection =DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://midominio.org:3306/nombreDB", "usuario", "contraseña");

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileFilter imageFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Imágenes", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
        chooser.setFileFilter(imageFilter);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        if(file != null)
        {
            BufferedImage img;
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                img=ImageIO.read(file);

                Image img2 = img.getScaledInstance(50, 67, 50);

                ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img2);

                fotoLb.setIcon(icon);

                fotoLb.revalidate();
                fotoLb.repaint();

                int anchura = img.getHeight();
                int altura = img.getWidth();

                img = Login.getfunciones().resizePhoto(img, 100,((100*anchura)/altura));
                ImageIO.write(img, "jpg",file);
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                String sentencia = "UPDATE persona SET FOTOGRAFIA = ? WHERE id_persona = ?";

                PreparedStatement pst;
                try {
                    pst = connection.prepareStatement(sentencia);
                    pst.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());
                    pst.setInt(2,idPersona);

                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    pst.close();

                } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {

                }
            }

public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage bufferedImage, int newW, int newH) {
        int w = bufferedImage.getWidth();
        int h = bufferedImage.getHeight();
        BufferedImage bufim = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, bufferedImage.getType());
        Graphics2D g = bufim.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g.dispose();
        return bufim;
    }
```

Le doy un nuevo tamaño al BufferedImage y convierto a tipo File, Despues para que no se deforme la foto dejo la anchura a un valor fijo (100pixels) y la altura saco su valor correspondiente.